# Редактирование бинарных файлов

Tags: c#, .net

Проблема в том что есть бинарный файл (Students.bin) нужно написать редактирование студента по айди (вводится айди и по нему нужно редактировать данные) не могу записать измененные данный, а когда они записываются то не полностью и возникает ошибка что нельзя считать данные поза потоком.Метод **SelectWhatEditStudent** Все методы и функции которые нужно знать для исправления находятся в проекте (ссылка на скачивание проекта ниже, потому что не могу вставить так много кода) **Administrator.cs**.
Ссылка на скачивание проекта https://dropmefiles.com/giH61
Текст ошибки при первом запуске

> Wyjatek nieobsluzony: System.ArgumentNullException: Wartosc nie moze byc zerowa.
> Nazwa parametru: value
> w System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)
> w Electronic_journal.Student.SaveStudents(List`1 students) w C:\Users\User\Desktop\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\E>lectronic_journal\Student.cs:wiersz 144
> w Electronic_journal.Administrator.SelectWhatEditStudent(Int32 ID) w C:\Users\User\Desktop\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Administrator.cs:wiersz 143
> w Electronic_journal.Administrator.EditStudent() w C:\Users\User\Desktop\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Administrator.cs:wiersz 77
> w Electronic_journal.MenuProgram..ctor() w C:\Users\User\Desktop\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\MenuProgram.cs:wiersz 122
> w Electronic_journal.Program.Main(String[] args) w C:\Users\User\Desktop\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Program.cs:wiersz 13

Текст ошибки при втором запуске

> Wyjatek nieobsluzony: System.ArgumentNullException: Wartosc nie moze
> byc zerowa. Nazwa parametru: value    w
> System.IO.BinaryWriter.Write(String value)    w
> Electronic_journal.Student.SaveStudents(List`1 students) w
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Student.cs:wiersz
> 143    w Electronic_journal.Administrator.SelectWhatEditStudent(Int32
> ID) w
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Administrator.cs:wiersz 126    w Electronic_journal.Administrator.EditStudent() w
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Administrator.cs:wiersz 77    w Electronic_journal.MenuProgram..ctor() w
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\MenuProgram.cs:wiersz
> 122    w Electronic_journal.Program.Main(String[] args) w
> C:\Users\User\Desktop\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Electronic_journal\Program.cs:wiersz
> 13

Код класса Student

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Electronic_journal
{
    class Student
    {
        public int Id = -1;//Айди студента (индификатор, личный номер)
        public string Surname { get; set; }//Фамилия
        public string Name { get; set; }//Имя
        public string Middlename { get; set; }//Очество
        public int Age { get; set; }//Возраст
        public int Year_of_Birth { get; set; }//Год рождения
        public string Group { get; set; }//Группа (можно с буквами)
        public string Login { get; set; }//Логин
        public string Password { get; set; }//Пароль
        public static int CurrentId = -1;

        ///SET Задаем значение переменным
        public void SetSurname()//Задаем фамилию
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите фамилию: ");
            Surname = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void SetName()//Задаем имя
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите имя: ");
             Name = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void SetMiddlename()//Задаем очество
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите отчество: ");
             Middlename = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void SetYear_of_birth()//Задаем год рождения
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите год рождение: ");
            string temp = Console.ReadLine();
            Year_of_Birth = Int32.Parse(temp);
        }
        //TODO: norm age (now is -....)
        public void SetAge()//Задаем возраст
        {
            //DateTime moment = new DateTime();
            //int year = moment.Year;
            //int year;
            //DateTime year = DateTime.Today;
            DateTime moment = new System.DateTime();
            //  int year = moment.Year;
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            int year = dt.Year;
            Age = year - Year_of_Birth;
        }

        public void SetGroup()//Задаем группу
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите группу: ");
             Group = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void SetLogin()//Задаем логин
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите логин: ");
             Login = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public void SetPassword()//Задаем пароль
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите пароль: ");
             Password = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static int GetLastId()//Получаем последний Id
        {
            return ++CurrentId;
        }
        public int NormId;
        public void SetIdd()
        {
            CurrentId = LoadStudentsId() + 1;
        }
        public void SetAll()//Задаем все переменные
        {
            //++Id;
                        
            SetSurname();
            SetName();
            SetMiddlename();
            SetYear_of_birth();
            SetAge();
            SetGroup();
            SetLogin();
            SetPassword();
            //GetLastId();

        }
        public string path = "Students.bin";

        public int LoadStudentsId()
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)))
            {
                List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
                while (br.PeekChar() > -1)
                {
                    ++Id;
                    Student student = new Student();
                    student.Id = br.ReadInt32();
                    student.Surname = br.ReadString();
                    student.Name = br.ReadString();
                    student.Middlename = br.ReadString();
                    student.Year_of_Birth = br.ReadInt32();
                    student.Age = br.ReadInt32();
                    student.Group = br.ReadString();
                    student.Login = br.ReadString();
                    student.Password = br.ReadString();
                    students.Add(student);
                }
                return ++Id;
            }
        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{Id}: {Surname} {Name} {Middlename}, {Year_of_Birth}, {Age} лет  Группа: {Group}, {Login}:{Password}";
        }

        public void SaveStudents(List<Student> students)
        {
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write)))
            {
                foreach (Student student in students)
                {
                  
                    bw.Write(student.Id);
                    bw.Write(student.Surname);
                    bw.Write(student.Name);
                    bw.Write(student.Middlename);
                    bw.Write(student.Year_of_Birth);
                    bw.Write(student.Age);
                    bw.Write(student.Group);
                    bw.Write(student.Login);
                    bw.Write(student.Password);
                }
            }
        }

        public  List<Student> LoadStudents()
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("Students.bin")))
            {
                List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
                while (br.PeekChar() > -1)
                {
                    Student student = new Student();
                    student.Id = br.ReadInt32();
                    student.Surname = br.ReadString();
                    student.Name = br.ReadString();
                    student.Middlename = br.ReadString();
                    student.Year_of_Birth = br.ReadInt32();
                    student.Age = br.ReadInt32();
                    student.Group = br.ReadString();
                    student.Login = br.ReadString();
                    student.Password = br.ReadString();
                    students.Add(student);
                }
                return students;
            }
        }
        

        public void Povtor()
        {
            string pow = "";
            Console.WriteLine("Повторить регистрацию студента?");
            pow = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
            if (pow == "да")
            {
                Student s = new Student();
                s.SetIdd();
                int q = Student.CurrentId;
                s.SetAll();
                List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
                students.Add(new Student
                {
                    Id = q,
                    Surname = s.Surname,
                    Name = s.Name,
                    Middlename = s.Middlename,
                    Year_of_Birth = s.Year_of_Birth,
                    Age = s.Age,
                    Group = s.Group,
                    Login = s.Login,
                    Password = s.Password
                });

                s.SaveStudents(students);
                List<Student> loadedStudents = s.LoadStudents();
                foreach (Student student in loadedStudents)
                    Console.WriteLine(student);
            }
            else
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
        public void ViewMarks(int ID)
        {
            Marks m = new Marks();
            List<Marks> loadedMarks = m.LoadMarks();
            foreach (Marks mark in loadedMarks)
                Console.WriteLine(mark);
            var selectmarks = from mar in loadedMarks
                              where mar.IdStudent == ID
                              select mar;
            foreach(Marks mark in selectmarks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{ mark.Mark} { mark.dm} { mark.Subject} ");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Метод в котором ошибка

```
      public void SelectWhatEditStudent(int ID)
        {
            string n, sur, mid, grup, log, pas;
            int ye, i;
        Student s = new Student();
            List<Student> loadedStudents = s.LoadStudents();
            var select = from stu in loadedStudents
                         where stu.Id == ID
                         select stu;
            
            var r = select.ToList();
           
            foreach(Student studen in r)
            {
                i = studen.Id;
                n = studen.Name;
                sur = studen.Surname;
                mid = studen.Middlename;
                grup = studen.Group;
                log = studen.Login;
                pas = studen.Password;
                ye = studen.Year_of_Birth;
            }
            List< Student > students = new List<Student>();
            string[] items = new string[] { "Сделай выбор оперции, выбирай стрелками вниз-вверх, что бы поддтвердить нажми - Ентер\n",
"1: Имя", "2: Фамилию", "3: Отчество","4: Год рождения", "5: Группу", "6: Логин", "7: Пароль"};
            Menu menu = new Menu(items);
            int menuResult;
            menuResult = menu.PrintMenu();
            switch (menuResult)
            {
                case 1:
                    //s.SetName();
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите новое имя:");
                    n = Console.ReadLine();                    
                    students.Add(new Student
                    {
                        Id = s.Id,
                        Surname = s.Surname,
                        Name = n,
                        Middlename = s.Middlename,
                        Year_of_Birth = s.Year_of_Birth,
                        Age = s.Age,
                        Group = s.Group,
                        Login = s.Login,
                        Password = s.Password
                    });
                    s.SaveStudents(students);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите новую фамилию:");
                    string surname = Console.ReadLine();
                    students.Add(new Student
                    {
                        Id = s.Id,
                        Surname = surname,
                        Name = s.Name,
                        Middlename = s.Middlename,
                        Year_of_Birth = s.Year_of_Birth,
                        Age = s.Age,
                        Group = s.Group,
                        Login = s.Login,
                        Password = s.Password
                    });
                    s.SaveStudents(students);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите новое отчетсво:");
                    string middlename = Console.ReadLine();
                    students.Add(new Student
                    {
                        Id = s.Id,
                        Surname = s.Surname,
                        Name = s.Name,
                        Middlename = middlename,
                        Year_of_Birth = s.Year_of_Birth,
                        Age = s.Age,
                        Group = s.Group,
                        Login = s.Login,
                        Password = s.Password
                    });
                    s.SaveStudents(students);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите новый год рождения:");
                    string temp = Console.ReadLine();
                    int year = Int32.Parse(temp);
                    students.Add(new Student
                    {
                        Id = s.Id,
                        Surname = s.Surname,
                        Name = s.Name,
                        Middlename = s.Middlename,
                        Year_of_Birth = year,
                        Age = s.Age,
                        Group = s.Group,
                        Login = s.Login,
                        Password = s.Password
                    });
                    s.SaveStudents(students);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите новую группу:");
                    string group = Console.ReadLine();
                    students.Add(new Student
                    {
                        Id = s.Id,
                        Surname = s.Surname,
                        Name = s.Name,
                        Middlename = s.Middlename,
                        Year_of_Birth = s.Year_of_Birth,
                        Age = s.Age,
                        Group = group,
                        Login = s.Login,
                        Password = s.Password
                    });
                    s.SaveStudents(students);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите новый логин:");
                    string login = Console.ReadLine();
                    students.Add(new Student
                    {
                        Id = s.Id,
                        Surname = s.Surname,
                        Name = s.Name,
                        Middlename = s.Middlename,
                        Year_of_Birth = s.Year_of_Birth,
                        Age = s.Age,
                        Group = s.Group,
                        Login = login,
                        Password = s.Password
                    });
                    s.SaveStudents(students);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Console.WriteLine("Введите новый пароль:");
                    string pass = Console.ReadLine();
                    students.Add(new Student
                    {
                        Id = s.Id,
                        Surname = s.Surname,
                        Name = s.Name,
                        Middlename = s.Middlename,
                        Year_of_Birth = s.Year_of_Birth,
                        Age = s.Age,
                        Group = s.Group,
                        Login = s.Login,
                        Password = pass
                    });
                    s.SaveStudents(students);
                    break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу");
            Console.ReadKey();
            
        }
```

Comment: Я могу вам дать ответ, что нужно сделать, даже не видя ваш код. Всегда читайте весь список студентов полностью. Держите его в памяти. Редактируете нужные записи, добавляете новые или удаляете старые. После чего записываете сразу весь список в файл. Не добавляете в файл, а перезаписываете!

Comment: это и делаю, но проблема с записю новых данных они не правильно записываются

Comment: `ArgumentNullException` - открываете документацию и смотрите, что означает это исключение. Смотрите в тексте ошибки номер строки, где произошло исключение. Исправляете. PS: вы передаёте значение `null` на запись.